# Which version of SageMath was I using? In 2018 that allowed this code to run?

Tags: python, version-control, sage

At some point the code bellow was working but now I need to replace the map line with something else. I'm wondering what version of SageMath I was using that my code was working. It may have been SageMath for python2 because It also had xrange() in the code. Additionally the new version throws errors on ^ ^ which was fine in the old version but now throws errors when it is compiled into ** **. I'm going to stick with the python 3 version and try to get it working I just need to fix the indexing because it was working fine with the Ubuntu python environment I was working with in 2018 but now on my mac in 2023 the updates have caused a few errors. python 3.10.10 is the version im using now and SageMath version 9.8, Release Date: 2023-02-11. Any help figuring out the old version though to get the original working would be appreciated.

```
def aes_encrypt(round_key, plain):
    R.< x >= GF(2)[]
    F = GF(2).extension(x ^ 8 + x ^ 4 + x ^ 3 + x + 1, 'a')
    a = F.gen()
    plain  # '0189fe7623abdc5445cdba3267ef9810'
    ar = map(ord, plain))  # .decode('hex')
    #ar = list(map(ord, plain))  # .decode('hex')) NEW VERSION FIX
    print('printing AR')
    print_ar(ar)
    k = 0
    while k < 10:  # each round
        round = k*16
        print("round_key")
        print_key(round_key, k)
        print('END of KEY ',type(round_key),round_key[0])
        print(type(ar),' TYPE ar ')
        print(list(ar))
        print("XOR")
        for x in range(0, 4):
            #print(ar[x]," "," ",round_key[4*x+16*k])
            ar[x] = ar[x] ^^round_key[4*x+16*k]
            ar[x+4] = ar[x+4] ^^round_key[4*x+1+16*k]
            ar[x+8] = ar[x+8] ^^round_key[4*x+2+16*k]
            ar[x+12] = ar[x+12] ^^round_key[4*x+3+16*k]
```

Answer (score 1):

Sage9.0, [released in January 2020](https://wiki.sagemath.org/ReleaseTours/sage-9.0), was the first sage to default to python3. By Sage9.2 towards the end of 2020, sage dropped python2 support.

This is the source of problems with `xrange`. In python2, `xrange` was how you obtained an iterator. But in python3, `range` returns an iterator.

To concretely answer your question: any sage version up to 8.9 would probably run your previous code. Sage versions 8.1 to 8.6 cover all of 2018. You can see more on the [release tours](https://wiki.sagemath.org/ReleaseTours/) page.

But I note that your code snippet won't actually run as is on any sage, as there are several things undefined. You don't do anything with `plain`; both `print_ar` and `print_key` are undefined; and you don't augment `k` in the while loop, so it's currently an infinite loop.

Barring those problems, the only other thing you need to do to update your code to the python3 switch is to use `ar = list(map(ord, plain)))` (as `map()` now also returns a generator, but you refer to it multiple times).

The notation `^^` still means `exclusive-or` in sage. Note that this requires the sage preprocessor, which only runs on `.sage` files or when used interactively. So calling `sage mysagefile.py` actually *doesn't* run the sage preprocessor, because the file extension isn't `.sage`.

If you don't use `.sage` files, then you can't use `^` to mean exponentiation and `^^` to mean xor.

You can also explicitly call xor through a function, such as with

```py
xor = lambda x, y: x.__xor__(y)
xor(5, 1)  # 4
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I know the full code was running at one point. I'll have to keep working on it to see if I can get the right set up combo which makes the full code work. Ill provide and update sometime this week.